# How do I map <S-Space> to Esc in XVim?

Tags: xcode, vim, xvim

I've been using Vim for a long time an unfortunately I've got very used to using `<S-Space>` to exit insert mode. Old habits die hard.

It seems when I put

```
imap <S-Space> <Esc>
```

in my `.xvimrc` it ignores the `Shift` part as interprets it as just `Space`. I think some time ago I read somewhere that that's an issue with OSX (they just didn't think anybody will ever need to type a 'capital space').

The way I solved that with Vim in iTerm2 is just map a character I'll never use (`✠`) to `<S-Space>` in iTerm2 and then use that in my `.vimrc`.

Any idea how I can make `<S-Space>` work in XVim?

Comment: sounds like you already know this but [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5388562/cant-map-s-cr-in-vim) is a related question for future readers

Comment: yeah except that's a solution specific to iterm2. any idea of a workaround for xcode?

Comment: Map your `<S-Space>` at OS level - to generate `<Esc>` for all applications. You may like it ;)

Comment: What do you mean by 'map at OS level'? You can't do it in Settings>Keyboard, is there another way to map key combinations for OSX?